# TinyMCE or CKeditor intergration problems with Zend

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework, tinymce, ckeditor

The folder structure looks like this:

```
Application
-- Layouts
---- layout.phtml (the 'template' file which loads all the .phtml files into, like insert.phtml form the pages folder, and loads init.js)
-- Modules
---- Admin
------ Views
-------- Scripts
---------- Pages
------------ insert.phtml (the actual file where I want to use tinyMCE)
Library
Public
-- Tinymce
---- tiny_mc.js
-- Jquery
---- init.js (loads the tiny_mce.js file using this code:
```

I call this to a textarea using Loader, and that looks like this:

```
$('.textEditor').Loader({
  url: ['../../../tinymce/tiny_mce.js'],
  debug: [true],
  cache: [true],
  success: function(target){
   tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    editor_selector : "textEditor",
    plugins : "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,
   });
  }
 });
```

When I look into my console I get this:

```
Loading: ../../../tinymce/tiny_mce.js
Loaded: ../../../tinymce/tiny_mce.js (126ms)
/dgpcms/public/admin/pages/insert//langs/en.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/dgpcms/public/admin/pages/insert//plugins/style/editor_plugin.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/dgpcms/public/admin/pages/insert//plugins/layer/editor_plugin.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/dgpcms/public/admin/pages/insert//plugins/table/editor_plugin.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/dgpcms/public/admin/pages/insert//themes/advanced/editor_template.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

.... and so on for all plugins ....

How can I get tinyMCE to ignore the MVC structure of the Zend App?
Or how to solve this problem...

Thanks in advance

This is the contents of my .htacces file as found in my public folder:

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|txt|swf)$ index.php
```

**Edit: 03-11-2010**

Changed something in the .htaccess file, and changed it back how it was setup before (as in the above situation), but the error has changed:

```
Loading: ../../../tinymce/tiny_mce.js
Loaded: ../../../tinymce/tiny_mce.js (230ms)
/langs/en.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/themes/advanced/editor_template.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/plugins/layer/editor_plugin.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/plugins/table/editor_plugin.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/plugins/save/editor_plugin.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

And so on for all plugins

So it's now looking in an other folder then before. Anybody any idea?

**Edit: 05-11-2010**

This is really bugging me out! I tried it with CKeditor, but the same problem occurs. I tried putting a .htaccess file in the folder (both for tinyMCE and CKeditor) with 'RewriteEngine Off', but that didn't make any difference.

**Edit: 22-11-2010**

Loading the tinyMCE on my layout file works. Not the best solution in this way, but it's better then nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not really an answer to this. Since this question my setup has changed a lot. I use Loader to load all the texteditor settings and that works great. I don't know if this question can be removed or closed but I don't think it will contribute in anyway....

There is not really an good answer (both are equaly in value in my opinion) so I'm accepting this one so it is answered/closed in a way.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your putting this JS code on the view , but i would do some modification

```
    <?php
          $this->headScript()->captureStart();
                        /* insert some javascript here */
    $('.textEditor').Loader({
      url: [$this->baseUrl("tinymce/tiny_mce.js")],
      //// don't forget to add the rest of your javascript code here 
     });
         $this->headScript()->captureEnd();
    echo $this->headScript();
    ?>
```

now `$this->baseUrl()` will calculate the best link instead of hard-coding it manually for more info check out http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html

Comment: The tiny_mce.js is called from an external file (init.js) which is called in the layout template, and therefore I cannot use any php in the code.

Comment: then you gatta use absolute url

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just use:

```
$('.textEditor').Loader({
    url: ['/tinymce/tiny_mce.js'],
    ...
```

Comment: No I can't because now it's not pointing to the tiny_mce.js file

Comment: Why, what is the path to your tiny_mce.js file? Can you also post the contents of your .htaccess.

Comment: ../../../tiny_mce.js is the correct path to the file, I need to go back three directory's...
the contents of my .htaccess file is added to my original post

Comment: Okay, nothing wrong with your htaccess. Presumably your vhost does point at /dgpcms/public, right? You need to use an absolute path though, forget about relative paths. I still don't see why /tinymce/tiny_mce.js won't work - what do you get if you view http://yourdomain.com/tinymce/tiny_mce.js in a browser?

Comment: http://localhost/dgpcms/public/tinymce/tiny_mce.js displays the contents of the js file, and no error what so ever in the console...

Comment: Okay, that's your problem. Your vhost should be pointing at dgpcms/public, it's not. You'll probably find that loading tinymce using /dgpcms/public/tinymce/tiny_mce.js as the path will work, but you really want your vhost to be pointing at the correct place.

Comment: Pointing to that url doesn't work either... How do I point my vhost? And I need it to work on a shared hosting as well as a dedicated one, so I don't want to be depended on stuff which I possible won't have access too.